# MVVM Data Model - Handle Array Type property

Tags: swift, mvvm

I have a JSON Response for Article Data(Nested Recommendations Array Data) which needs to be converted to the respective data object. I'm unable to handle the nested JSONArray that is recommendations. How would we do so?

```
// RESPONSE STARTS HERE
{
    "title":"TITLE",
    "detail":"Details Body",
    "recommendations":[ 
      {
        "text":"recomm 1",
        "createdAt":"ISODATE"
      }, 
      {
        "text":"recomm 2",
        "createdAt":"ISODATE"
      }
    ]
}
// RESPONSE ENDS HERE
```

I have two Data types here, Article & Recommendation. I have the following **ArticleBaseClass** & **RecommendationBaseClass**. How to handle the Array of Recommendations conversion. (Point Mentioned in Code, ArticleBaseClass)

**ArticleBaseClass**

```
public final class ArticleBaseClass: NSCoding {

  // MARK: Declaration for string constants to be used to decode and also serialize.
  private struct SerializationKeys {
    static let title = "title"
    static let detail = "detail"
    static let recommendation = "recommendation"
  }

  // MARK: Properties
  public var title: String?
  public var detail: String?
  public var recommendation: [RecommendationsBaseClass]?

  // MARK: SwiftyJSON Initializers
  /// Initiates the instance based on the object.
  ///
  /// - parameter object: The object of either Dictionary or Array kind that was passed.
  /// - returns: An initialized instance of the class.
  public convenience init(object: Any) {
    self.init(json: JSON(object))
  }

  /// Initiates the instance based on the JSON that was passed.
  ///
  /// - parameter json: JSON object from SwiftyJSON.
  public required init(json: JSON) {
    title = json[SerializationKeys.title].string
    detail = json[SerializationKeys.detail].string

    //THIS IS THE POINT THAT FAILS//
    recommendation = json[SerializationKeys.recommendation].array.flatMap { RecommendationsBaseClass(json: $0) } 
    //--------//
  }

  /// Generates description of the object in the form of a NSDictionary.
  ///
  /// - returns: A Key value pair containing all valid values in the object.
  public func dictionaryRepresentation() -> [String: Any] {
    var dictionary: [String: Any] = [:]
    if let value = title { dictionary[SerializationKeys.title] = value }
    if let value = detail { dictionary[SerializationKeys.detail] = value }
    if let value = recommendation { dictionary[SerializationKeys.recommendation] = value }
    return dictionary
  }

  // MARK: NSCoding Protocol
  required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: SerializationKeys.title) as? String
    self.detail = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: SerializationKeys.detail) as? String
    self.recommendation = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: SerializationKeys.recommendation) as? String
  }

  public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(title, forKey: SerializationKeys.title)
    aCoder.encode(detail, forKey: SerializationKeys.detail)
    aCoder.encode(recommendation, forKey: SerializationKeys.recommendation)
  }

}
```

**RecommendationsBaseClass**

```
public final class RecommendationsBaseClass: NSCoding {

  // MARK: Declaration for string constants to be used to decode and also serialize.
  private struct SerializationKeys {

    static let text = "text"
    static let createdAt = "createdAt"
  }

  // MARK: Properties

  public var text: String?

  public var createdAt: String?

  // MARK: SwiftyJSON Initializers
  /// Initiates the instance based on the object.
  ///
  /// - parameter object: The object of either Dictionary or Array kind that was passed.
  /// - returns: An initialized instance of the class.
  public convenience init(object: Any) {
    self.init(json: JSON(object))
  }

  /// Initiates the instance based on the JSON that was passed.
  ///
  /// - parameter json: JSON object from SwiftyJSON.
  public required init(json: JSON) {

    text = json[SerializationKeys.text].string
    createdAt = json[SerializationKeys.createdAt].string
  }

  /// Generates description of the object in the form of a NSDictionary.
  ///
  /// - returns: A Key value pair containing all valid values in the object.
  public func dictionaryRepresentation() -> [String: Any] {
    var dictionary: [String: Any] = [:]
    if let value = text { dictionary[SerializationKeys.text] = value }
    if let value = createdAt { dictionary[SerializationKeys.createdAt] = value }
    return dictionary
  }

  // MARK: NSCoding Protocol
  required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.text =  aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: SerializationKeys.text) as? String
    self.createdAt = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: SerializationKeys.createdAt) as? String
  }

  public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(text, forKey: SerializationKeys.text)
    aCoder.encode(createdAt, forKey: SerializationKeys.createdAt)
  }

}
```

Comment: So? What's the issue?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about my question. I'm unable to handle the nested JSON Array (i.e: Recommendations). How would I convert that into Object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to convert from JSON to swift data model (try it out on playground):

```swift
import Foundation

struct Model: Codable {
    let title, detail: String
    let recommendations: [Recommendation]
}

struct Recommendation: Codable {
    let text, createdAt: String
}


let json = """
{
    "title":"TITLE",
    "detail":"Details Body",
    "recommendations":[
      {
        "text":"recomm 1",
        "createdAt":"ISODATE"
      },
      {
        "text":"recomm 2",
        "createdAt":"ISODATE"
      }
    ]
}
"""
let data = Data(json.utf8)
let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: data)
print(model)
```